# Android InputConnection: get notified when selection changes

Tags: android, android-input-method

I want my `InputMethodService` to switch to capitals when the cursor is positioned after a period (`'.'`) and spaces. The trick is to get notified when the cursor is re-positioned. The cursor may get positioned after a period when either:

1. user inputs period, or
2. user touches the screen, or
3. user pastes some text.

Question: how do I get the `InputMethodService` notified of selection changes and text pasting?

Answer (score 0):

There is [InputMethodService.onUpdateSelection (int oldSelStart, int oldSelEnd, int newSelStart, int newSelEnd, int candidatesStart, int candidatesEnd)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateSelection%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) that does the trick.

You could try to find something like that in `InputConnection` (like I did), but there's no <strike>`InputConnection.getSelection()`</strike> or <strike>`InputConnection.onSelectionChanged()`</strike>.